# How do I disable Chrome's two-finger back/forward navigation?

Tags: google-chrome, multi-touch

Chrome supports two-finger swipes left/right in order to browse back/forward in the browser history. Unfortunately, Chrome handles this differently to other macOS applications, and it's far too easy to accidentally trigger it while you're in the middle of a long down/up scroll, which needless to say occurs often.

I generally like the gesture, and things like Preview, Safari, and other application have implemented it much better, where you cannot blindly navigate back/forward so long as you have begun to scroll up/down.

How do I selectively disable two-finger back/forward navigation in Chrome?

Comment: This sounds like a poor implementation on Chrome's part. Have you considered filing a bug?

Comment: Actually, I just tried to reproduce this and it doesn't seem to be happening for me in the latest dev build. Are you sure you're up to date?

Comment: I'm on the latest dev build and I can confirm this error.  I would file a bug with the Chrome team.  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: If you don't have to be on the dev version, it's less sensitive in the beta channel

Comment: That's not a suitable answer by virtue of the fact that (in theory), any other channel will eventually have the current state of the dev channel.

Comment: It's also easy to do if the page is wide and you are simply trying to scroll all the way back to the left.

Comment: 100 million times ^

Comment: Judging by the number of votes and views on this page, this should be disabled by default.

Comment: Please up vote this defect: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=854881

Comment: The only time I've ever used this feature is by accident

Comment: It also makes lateral scrolling impossible

Comment: Chrome's god awful horizontal scrolling behavior makes lateral scrolling difficult. I asked this question and wanted to turn it off because (1) 90% of the desktop web doesn't require horizontal scrolling (and even less of the mobile web), and (2) it is that Chrome's implementation of it is so poor that when I *want* to horizontally scroll, I wind up navigating back instead which completely screws up page state. I can still do shift+scroll to do horizontal, which is way better, and dealing with a "why isn't horizontally scrolling working?" moment is acceptable to remind me to do that instead.

Comment: Just to note that this bug report listed by @rouble was marked as "Won't do" after 3 years of inattention.

Answer (score 579, accepted):

I know its over a year later, but I had the same question, and then figured out the answer myself.

Open terminal and type:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE
```

Then restart Chrome.

Now you can have it enabled system wide, and just disabled for chrome. By the way, this works for any app, just replace com.google.Chrome with the bundle identifier of the target app.

If your interested in how it works, the AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls is the global setting, that can be overwritten for any specified app.

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Oh yes. Oh my god yes. This is EXCELLENT. It helped me, NOW. THANK YOU!

Comment: I want to create a hundred accounts just to keep upvoting this answer as many times as humanly possible.

Comment: Works for me on Mavericks without the `.plist`

Comment: How to make it automatic? (For me it works, but after system restart I need to do it again.)

Comment: You never need the .plist. Can you remove that part of the answer?

Comment: Tried this in Yosemite and it doesn't seem to work (even after restarting Chrome). This is super annoying - especially when I am entering information (say, writing an answer on SE), and scroll to check something - it's rather easy to end up going back, and losing your edit. Does this answer need an update for Yosemite?

Comment: We need to be able to control this behavior in the web app (We're building an app that has a horizontally scrolling layout)...

Comment: This worked for me in Yosemite and Chrome 41 - but I was trying it with a magic mouse so had to use @fredy-muñoz answer...

Comment: Worked for Chrome 44 in Yosemite 10.10.4 with a Bluetooth Logitech mouse.

Comment: So much better! Worked for me on Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

Comment: This stopped working for me, but then I realized that Chrome was in the middle of an update and needed to be restarted (`Chrome` > `About Google Chrome` > `Relaunch`).

Comment: For Yosemite + Chrome latest stable 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit):

`defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE` 

works perfectly for me after restarting Chrome.

(Note previous answers mentioned 
`defaults write com.google.Chrome.plist AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE` 
but the extraneous `.plist` suffix made it a NOOP.)

Comment: Awesome! Works for Safari too!!! `defaults write com.apple.Safari AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`.  Just what I was looking for. Two-finger swipe is also for horizontal scroll and scrolling in a text area that contains an oversized image can initiate the "back button" which obliterated my work filling out the form. Not cool. They should make it 3-finger or something at least.

Comment: This worked for me after I restarted my computer.

Comment: I know this is the opposite of what the question asked, but I just used this to enable two finger swipe to go back by switching FALSE to TRUE like so: `defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool TRUE`

Comment: Works on El Capitan and Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). Had to completely quit Chrome and restart it. No system reboot needed.

Comment: Still working on Sierra (10.12.5) and Chrome 59.0.3071.115. Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me on Sierra and Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit). Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Saved my day.  Finally disabled the most hated feature.

Comment: For me this was the only way that worked.

Comment: how do i find out the bundle identifier of the target app? Asking because I am using Brave Browser which is based on Chrome

Comment: Still works for Big Sur!

Comment: Still works on Chrome 89!

Comment: Edge users: `defaults write com.microsoft.edgemac AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`

Comment: not working in windows 10

Comment: For Brave Browser: `defaults write com.brave.Browser AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`

Comment: If you don't want to use a terminal you can navigate to `chrome://flags` and set Overscroll History Navigation" to Disabled

`chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation`

Comment: This is the money!

Comment: Worked in 2023. Thanks

Comment: Works great with Arc too: `defaults write company.thebrowser.Browser AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`

Answer (score 233):

I went into the System Prefs and changed the Page change gesture from two fingers to three (OSX Lion). The three finger swipe seems to be more responsive at any rate and I'm usually only using two fingers for everything else.

System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures > Swipe between pages

Comment: ...this works, though you're also changing the setting for every other app (including Preview). I like this solution and it's what I'm doing, but I'm hoping the Chrome people will read this thread and see that they need to offer a fix within the browser.

Comment: Also works for Mountain Lion.

Comment: IMHO this is a better solution than changing the Chrome defaults with the command line command.

Comment: Works in Mavericks when the command line option did not.

Comment: Works fine in Yosemite also. Some people might like the swiping/gesture stuff but I don't really, so I changed it to three-finger swipe (which should avoid false positives).

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I love the two finger gesture for navigatin the browsind history and used it ever since. But now, as I used floor planning web apps such as http://community.planningwiz.com/ and http://www.homestyler.com/floorplan with their 2D/3D views, where the gesture is used for view panning, I had triggered the history back action accidentially way too often, which was annoying as it always exited the app back to the home screen and thereby discarded my work... So I needed a temporary deactivation while working with these apps. Thanks!

Comment: You saved my day. 
Command option didn't work for me in El Capitan

Comment: 1 finger makes all the difference!!

Comment: I turn off all gestures, as I just realized I never use any of them.

Answer (score 62):

**Summary:**

It looks like Google Chrome uses Apples default gestures, so by disabling Apples gestures you disable Chromes. However, you probably still love some gestures like I do. For that get BetterTouchTools.

**Disable Google Chromes Gestures**

You can disable chromes gestures by going to System Preference > Mouse OR Trackpad > More Gestures > and uncheck Swipe between pages.

**Keep the Gestures You Want**

I still love gestures so I downloaded BetterTouchTools which allows me to make the gestures I want. I disabled all apples gestures then created my own. You can get very custom with gestures this way. Or if you prefer, leave some of apples gestures on and use BetterTouchTools for the more custom ones.

Comment: How do you enable the Swipe between pages gesture for other applications?? The gesture is missing in the BetterTouchTools.

Comment: @PetrPeller Each application should have its own keyboard shortcut for swiping between pages. In BetterTouchTools you can setup custom gestures for each application. Setup an new application, use whatever gesture you want for a swipe, then enter that applications keyboard shortcut for the gestures action. Make sense?

Comment: @zechdc But that way I would have to set up every single application separately and I would miss the animation as the gesture would be translated into keyboard shortcut. It's a pity that the BetterTouchTools can't just disable the 2-finger swipe gesture for Google Chrome and leave default behaviour for different apps.

Comment: @PetrPeller I agree. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Can you disable the two finger horizontal swipe gestures on a per app basis with BetterTouchTools, i.e. to disable this for Chrome only, but still use it in Preview.app, Safari, etc? If not, with which other tools or with which config file tweaks or command lines?

Comment: @prog You cannot disable system default gestures with BetterTouchTools. You can only add additional gestures. My recommendation is to disable Mac's default gestures, then create your own. You can create new gestures on a per app basis. For example, you can setup a swipe action in BTT to use the `CMD` + `[` hotkey which will make safari go back in history one page. Does that make sense?

Comment: love this option, gestures are useful, it's just a conflict when I'm scrolling horizontall and I reach the boundary, so it thinks I'm trying to navigate. I've changed it to a 3-finger swipe, so I still have a quick gesture. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, plus it looks like advertising. BetterTouchTools is a commercial software.

Comment: @DavidAmmouial, true. When I wrote this answer BetterTouchTools was free. I no longer use it because this hasn't been an issue for more anymore. At the time, 9 years ago, it worked well.

Answer (score 50):

There are two different properties, one is for the **Trackpad**: `AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls`, the other is for the **Mouse/Magic Mouse**: `AppleEnableMouseSwipeNavigateWithScrolls`.

So you need to execute one or both of these commands:

```sh
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableMouseSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool false
defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool false
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Couldn't figure out for the life of me why this was working for everyone else but me—it was because I'm using a Magic Mouse and needed `AppleEnableMouseSwipeNavigateWithScrolls`.

Comment: This is the answer needed if you're using an Apple Magic Mouse 2.

Comment: awesome, I almost got crazy about this, when some pages needed vertical scrolling and instead it navigated ...

Answer (score 14):

Chrome Canary users should use:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome.canary AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE
```

Comment: During my testing the com.google.Chrome.canary.plist should be com.google.Chrome.canary.

Comment: I used com.google.Chrome.dev to enable it on the dev version (which now has it disabled by default) thanks for the inspiration

Answer (score 14):

I also tried the terminal command on Yosemite, it didn't work for me.

And then I tried uncheck "Swipe between pages" in mouse settings, and it worked.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for you since you are using a Magic Mouse, and not a Magic Trackpad. Note @Fredy-Muñoz's answer. The instructions in this answer disable the feature *for all apps*. If this works for you, great. However, in my post / the original Question, I asked about selectively disabling it for Chrome. See the accepted answer or Fredy's for more information.

Answer (score 9):

This is available as the `#overscroll-history-navigation` flag in `chrome://flags`

> **Overscroll history navigation**
> History navigation in response to horizontal overscroll. – Windows, Linux, Chrome OS
>
> `#overscroll-history-navigation`

There is an option called "disable click" on that. Then just restart Chrome.

Comment: Dont have such flag on MacOs Chrome Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: @AlexandreG you are correct, it appears that flag is only exposed on Windows, Linux, Chrome OS

Comment: The only working solution for Google Crome on Windows 10. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The only way I'm currently of is two disable two-finger page swiping system-wide, from the Trackpad section of System Preferences. I wait patiently for Chrome to either fix its implementation, or at least provide an app preference for disabling the feature.

Comment: I don't expect them to ever fix this.  They've been arguing in favor of an even stupider mis-feature for years, where hitting the [delete] key will go back a page if no fields have focus.  From a usability perspective, Chrome is a steaming pile .  It's main redeeming factors are (1) a superior Inspector, and (2) more and better extensions.  Otherwise it would be worthless.