# What application can record a cursor location and multi-touch input heatmap?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

Are there any applications out there that can record mouse interaction, and save a standard image<sup>1</sup> that adequately conveys the exact situation that using the mouse created?

Due to the proliferation of gestures in Lion, I would like to include an image conveying exactly what I do in bug reports. Take for example my question regarding [Chrome's use of Two-finger forward/back gestures](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21236/how-do-i-disable-chromes-two-finger-back-forward-navigation). I would love to attach an image that conveys my exact touch pad usage (and a standard mouse could be beneficial too in other cases) when filing a bug report regarding my gesture grievance.

---

<sup>1</sup> Where standard image file is something like an animated gif, or perhaps an annotated jpg/png with indicators of finger number, and stroke direction.

Comment: With different color overlays for different finger gestures, YES PLEASE!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an app that displays gestures, but [FingerMgmt](http://blog.sendapatch.se/2009/november/multitouch-on-unibody-macbooks.html) displays the locations of your touches (and the size, dimension, etc.) in a window. You could record that to attach to your bug reports.

Comment: Nice application, I could couple that with screen recording software to make a very sophisticated Bug Report. I'd still love something that does the recording and exporting for me.