# How to disable swipe navigation on Edge for Mac

Tags: settings, multi-touch

Like Chrome, Edge for Mac supports browser navigation by dragging horizontally with two fingers on the trackpad. I know how to turn this off [in Chrome](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21236/how-do-i-disable-chromes-two-finger-back-forward-navigation), but is it possible to turn this off in Edge? Bonus gratitude for a command-line solution.

I've tried, without success...

- to access `edge://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation`, which appears to have been removed
- to deduce an equivalent of `defaults write com.google.Chrome AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE`
- to find an equivalent of Windows 10's `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI\Allow Edge Swipe`

Comment: Please list the things/suggestions you've tried, otherwise people will just propose the same things again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This appears to get the job done for me on Big Sur (11.2.3) with Microsoft Edge (89.0.774.57):

```
defaults write com.microsoft.edgemac AppleEnableSwipeNavigateWithScrolls -bool FALSE
```

Comment: After a restart of Edge, this works!  Thank you.

Comment: Is there some benefit to disabling it specifically for Edge, rather than in System Preferences?

Comment: @iconoclast My memory might be failing me but I don't think Edge respected the "Swipe between pages" setting in System Prefs back then.  If it respects it now then that's progress :)

Answer (score 23):

I found a solution in the trackpad settings. In System Preferences go to Trackpad > More Gestures. Then disable "Swipe between pages".

Comment: this worked me. this is the worst feature I ever encountered in whole my life as a computer user. thanks a lot

Comment: This did not work for me (MacOS Sonoma and Edge 120)